# offchain indexing for large files

Tags: pallet, offchain-worker, offchain, offchain-storage

I'm new to the project and currently working on a pallet, which is supposed to deal with large files offchain. Pallet, offchain indexing and the offchain worker are all working fine, still I get "Failed to upload file: RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits" on larger files

The referring extrinsic looks like this:

```
#[pallet::call_index(0)]
#[pallet::weight(200_000)]
pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, received_bytes: Vec<u8>, version: u8) -> DispatchResult { 
 // ...
 let block_number = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number();
 set_offchain_data::<T>(block_number, received_bytes);
 // ...
}
```

I receive the data through the persistent storage within the offchain_worker callback and can perform according actions. Am I wrong here, are the bytes already put onchain before `do_something` is called? and if so, is there a possibility to avoid this. I only wanna put the result/response of the data processing onchain.

Again I'm new to the system, might be that I have overseen something essential. Anyhow, happy for any here. Thanks a lot

Comment: How large is "larger files"? And why are you trying to store files on chain? You should only store the hash of the file on chain.

Comment: larger than the max block size, so everything > 3,4MB (give or take)

Comment: @bkchr I don't want to store these bytes onchain, they supposed to be processed by the offchain worker. I was hoping to do so by offchain indexing, but still it fails, if the byte size is larger than the block limit. The result of the offchain worker byte procession is supposed be stored onchain afterwards. This is basically just a hash.

Comment: But you are sending them to the chain, which essentially means that they are part of a block.

Comment: @bkchr Yes I know and my question is, how to avoid that. The offchain worker of my pallet should receive large amount  of data  ([u8], > 3MB) to process it and the result is a hash that I want to store on-chain. So how can I pass pass large amount of data  to the offchain worker without writing that onchain.

These bytes are passed through an attached web interface to the pallet and I cannot bypass that, so I need to use these bytes .

Comment: Any solution found??